Using Kusto scan operator to capture sequential pairs that meets criteria
I am trying to get the kusto scan operator to work for this use case. I want to create pairs where columnA matches.
let threecolumns = datatable( Ts: timespan, ColumnA: string, ColumnB: string) 
[
    0m, "aaa","023",
    1m, "aaa","134",
    2m, "aaa", "256",
    3m, "aaa", "356",
    4m, "aaa", "467",
    5m, "bbb", "578",
    6m, "bbb", "687",
    8m, "ccc", "788",
    11m, "ddd", "899",
    12m, "ddd", "988"];

For the above table, I'm looking to get a list this



Ts
ColumnA
ColumnB
isPair
A_1
B_1




0m
aaa
023
true
aaa
134


2m
aaa
256
true
aaa
356


5m
bbb
578
true
bbb
687


11m
ddd
899
true
ddd
988



This is what I've tried, and as you can see, I am getting an extra pair
let threecolumns = datatable( Ts: timespan,ColumnA:string, ColumnB: string) [
    0m, "aaa","023",
    1m, "aaa","134",
    2m, "aaa", "256",
    3m, "aaa", "356",
    4m, "aaa", "467",
    5m, "bbb", "578",
    6m, "bbb", "687",
    8m, "ccc", "788",
    11m, "ddd", "899",
    12m, "ddd", "988"
];
threecolumns
| partition hint.strategy=native by ColumnA
(
    order by Ts desc
    | extend A_1 = next(ColumnA, 1), B_1 = next(ColumnB, 1)
    | extend A_2 = next(ColumnA, 2), B_2 = next(ColumnB, 2)
    | scan with_match_id=m_id declare(paired: bool, step: string) with
    (
        step s1 output = last: (ColumnA == A_1 and paired != true) => paired = true, step = 's1';
        step s2 :(ColumnA == A_2 and s1.paired == true) =>  paired = false, step = 's2';
        step s3: (ColumnA != A_1) => paired = false, step = 's3';
    )
)
| where paired == true
| project Ts, ColumnA, ColumnB, paired, A_1, B_1





Ts
ColumnA
ColumnB
isPair
A_1
B_1




00:04:00
aaa
467
true
aaa
356


00:03:00
aaa
356
true
aaa
256


00:01:00
aaa
134
true
aaa
023


00:06:00
bbb
687
true
bbb
578


00:12:00
ddd
988
true
ddd
899




You can try below code to achieve your requirement.
let threecolumns = datatable( Ts: timespan,ColumnA:string, ColumnB: string) [
    0m, "aaa","023",
    1m, "aaa","134",
    2m, "aaa", "256",
    3m, "aaa", "356",
    4m, "aaa", "467",
    5m, "bbb", "578",
    6m, "bbb", "687",
    8m, "ccc", "788",
    11m, "ddd", "899",
    12m, "ddd", "988"
];
threecolumns
| partition hint.strategy=native by ColumnA
(
    order by Ts asc
    | extend A_1 = next(ColumnA, 1), B_1 = next(ColumnB, 1)
    | extend x=row_number()
    | where A_1 !=''
    | where x%2 == 1
)
| order by Ts asc
| project Ts, ColumnA, ColumnB, paired=true, A_1, B_1;

Result:


Thank you, much simpler and easier to understand too.
